# Upload large binary file to using Java Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, upload, binary, resttemplate

I have a servlet which is able to receive binary data [files].

I would like to use Spring's RestTemplate() to upload a large binary file to the servlet. However its not possible to load the binary file entirely into memory.

So far my attempts have resulted in OutOfMemory errors, indicating the methods have been attempting to load the entire file into memory.

How can I stream this binary data to the servlet? Preferable in Spring or otherwise in Java.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the answer:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7909

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

This prevents loading the entire request into memory.

Comment: Notice that this is fixed as of Spring version 3.1.
So this problem should no longer arise if you are using Spring version >= 3.1.
Otherwise, the code snippet above should solve the problem.

Comment: @Doron : I use Spring 3.2.5 but I met the same issue, i'm not sure that It was fixed.